# Store Input Box Data Temporally in VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a Windows Form application which will prompt for data to then update a SQL table.

The SQL table requires 3 fields, column A, column B, column C.

To make it easier for the end user, I'm trying to allow them to input all the data in for column C first (As they won't know the relevant data for Columns A and B until the end of the process when they request that data from a third party).

Is there a way to store all the data they add for column C, then at the end request a single piece of information for A and B, which will then populate the other two columns and update the SQL table with these rows?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple forms (a form for C and a different form for A and B)?

Comment: More `down to the ground` example would be nice. A, B and C is hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a datagridview with ADO.net.  Make the datagrid 3 columns wide, and utilize the first column (does it make more sense to fill out the first column rather than third?  You can update it back to the database in any order.)to expect the value that you want to capture (you can add more datagrid rows as needed). In order to do this query to the database, you can add a database through dataset designer and create a method to pull/update data to/from sql server.

To get data out of the DB, you could loop through each row of the datagridview, collect the column1 item, pass it as a parameter (if needed) to your new method, receive the data back from the database, fill the the other two columns in the row.

Now that you have that data you could do an entire update into the database using another method created in the dataset designer.